# Using STs I2C HAL Library to write no data to a register

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal

I need to write to a register to kick a device out of boot and into application mode for the using I2C on the [ST-Nucleo-F767ZI](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f767zi.html).  I am currently using the ST provided HAL function `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write` to write data to registers, but this function requires the data to not be `NULL`.  What is the correct way to ping a register using the ST HAL?  Is it `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the above question is that yes - the correct way to handle a ping of a register is via the `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit`.  This function will transmit the data provided - in this case the register address on the device.  The `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write` function is a higher level function which expects that the caller is writing data to the register; hence, in the function itself if the input `size` is 0 or `pData` is `NULL`, then the driver will throw `HAL_ERROR`.